# Woocommerce Storefront - Sticky Product Page Gallery

Tags: css, woocommerce, sticky, storefront

I'm using Storefront, a 'Woo' theme for Woocommerce. I've attempted to make the image gallery 'sticky'. Currently only contains 1 item. My plan was to make this item scroll down along side the product page description / add-to-cart section which on my site is quite complex and long.

My site isn't live at the moment, so here's the Storefront Demo:
https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/product/lowepro-slingshot-edge-250-aw/

I've used the basic explanation of Sticky from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

And tried applying that, logically I thought, like so

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery {
position: sticky!important;
top: 0!important;
}
```

This doesn't do the trick, so I tried targeting various other elements:

woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper

woocommerce-product-gallery__image

Neither work. Perhaps the answer is extending the height of that gallery column, but I'd want to do this without disrupting the normal function of the Storefront gallery. Important if I should add multiple images at a later time.

If anyone can see the obvious problem with Storefront and Sticky items do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer came to me via http://dinbror.dk/blog/help-css-position-sticky-doesnt-work-solved/

Woocommerce (or perhaps Storefront) body has the aforementioned overflow usage in a few placed.

```
body.single-product,
body.single-product #page,
body.single-product .product {
overflow: visible!important;
}
```

So remove relevant overflow statement (the snippet above worked for me) and the Woocommerce / Storefront gallery 'sticks' as per my original *SO* query.

Resolved.