# How to make the Product Page Gallery STICKY on a WooCommerce site with AVADA?

Tags: css, woocommerce, gallery, sticky

I have a WooCommerce site built with the Avada Theme. I've attempted to make the image gallery 'sticky' on product pages. **The idea is to make the Image Gallery scroll down  alongside the short product description / add-to-cart section on the right column**, which tends to be longer.

I saw a line of code on [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744375/woocommerce-storefront-sticky-product-page-gallery), which helped work out the code for the Avada theme (I'm using Avada's image gallery instead of WooCommerce's):

```
.avada-product-gallery {
position: sticky!important;
top: 0!important;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I get from the linked article, **this line of code hereabove would work, but needs ***overflow:visible***** on the body or bigger container where the gallery is.

I am learning coding at the moment so I'm kind of fishy on the subject - with all respect to fish. I have tried to trace back the container where I have to add the `overflow: visible!important`, but it's resisting me, so I am kind of lost with the code at something like:

```
XXXXXXXXXX .XXXXX {
overflow: visible!important;
}
```

I leave you an example of a product page I'd like to change to see if someone can help me identify the container which I have to refer on code to change the overflow display:
https://architectoutlet.com/shop/gifts/gifts-for-science-lovers/ti-asia-blue/

I come up with `.flex-viewpoint .product {` ?? `.Fusion-row .product {`?? avada-single-product-gallery-wrapper avada-product-images-global avada-product-images-thumbnails-left ??

I am all ears and open to learning, so any tip on the matter is welcome!

Thank you

best regards to all :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can add your own custom javascript**

`.avada-product-gallery` is your product page gallery class

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
   var width = jQuery(window).width();
   if (width > 767) {
   jQuery(".avada-product-gallery").stick_in_parent({offset_top:60});
  }
});
```

Tested & It's working from my end.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Savan, thank you for your interest.

I've added your code with Code Snippets as it looks here:

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
          jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
   var width = jQuery(window).width();
   if (width > 767) {
   jQuery(".avada-product-gallery").stick_in_parent({offset_top:60});
  }
});
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');


It doesn't seem to work. 
On the post I added a link to an example page of the site I am working on. 
Maybe I still have to change overflow to visible? tx

Comment: Where can you add the script? 
You can add javascript on the footer? @MalevichG

Comment: Hello Savan, yes I can, but the code you sent me doesn't seem to work